# Do calculate SNR based on mean and stdev need normalization?

Tags: python, mean, standard-deviation, signal-detection

How to calculate Signal to Noise Ratio?

Is the mean to stdev ratio valid to be used as the basis for calculating SNR?

What if a dataset or sample has a value of 0 all then add 1 random value other than 0 which is considered noise , for example it becomes `[0,0,0,...,0,1]` the samples/dataset is considered as clean signal with last of element is considered as noise.

The mean and stdev are close to 0 because all data is about 0 and the distribution is all about same which if the two values ​​are divided will be close to 1. SNR=1 means that the noise and signal have a balanced strength but in reality the dataset does not have a lot of noise.

Now with same case which is a clean signal too, what if the dataset has a value of 2 all? It will looks like
`[2,2,2,2,...,2,1]`

This means stdev close to 0 while mean is close to 2, if we divided it, the SNR will be bigger than 2 for example 1.99/0.001.

Why Both cases have different SNR value even though both of sample are clean signals?

EDIT:
I tried the formula in program, but it didn't give me same value:
$$\frac{\text{Var}(S) + E[S]^2}{\text{Var}(N) + E[N]^2}$$

```
import numpy as np

signal = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
expected = np.mean(signal)
noise = expected - signal
print((np.var(signal)+(np.square(np.mean(signal))))/(np.var(noise)+(np.square(np.std(signal)))))

signal = np.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
expected = np.mean(signal)
noise = expected - signal
print((np.var(signal)+np.square(np.mean(signal)))/(np.var(noise)+np.square(np.std(signal))))
```

OUTPUT:

```
0.5833333333333333
14.583333333333334
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for a mean-invariant version of SNR. Given the signal $S$ and the noise $N$, SNR is typically computed as $$\frac{E[S^2]}{E[N^2]}$$ This can also be written as $$\frac{\text{Var}(S) + E[S]^2}{\text{Var}(N) + E[N]^2}$$ where $\text{Var}(S)$ and $\text{Var}(N)$ are the variances of the signal and noise respectively. Therefore, the SNR depends on the mean value of the signal $E[S]$ and the mean value of the noise $E[N]$. Alternatively, you could compute SNR as $$\frac{\text{Var}(S)}{\text{Var}(N)}$$ However, this only takes into account the "spread" of the signal vs. the "spread" of the noise, and ignores their "DC value". In most cases, this is undesirable.

---

Here is a demonstration of this concept:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
# generate a random signal with mean 0 and the same signal with mean x
N = 500
x = 50
signal1 = np.random.randn(N)
signal2 = signal1 + x
# generate noise with mean 0 and mean x
noise1 = np.random.randn(N)
noise2 = noise1 + x
# print the SNR with and without the mean for both signals
print(
f"""Signal 1 (zero mean):
SNR with mean = {(np.var(signal1) + np.mean(signal1)**2)/(np.var(noise1) + np.mean(noise1)**2)}
SNR without mean = {np.var(signal1)/np.var(noise1)}

Signal 2 (mean x > 0):
SNR with mean = {(np.var(signal2) + np.mean(signal2)**2)/(np.var(noise2) + np.mean(noise2)**2)}
SNR without mean = {np.var(signal2)/np.var(noise2)}
"""
)
```

which yields the output

```
Signal 1 (zero mean):
SNR with mean = 1.0056515707726348
SNR without mean = 1.006669696804731

Signal 2 (mean x > 0):
SNR with mean = 0.99900428349472
SNR without mean = 1.0066696968047304
```

We see that, when we compute the SNR without the mean, as I did in the expression $$\frac{\text{Var}(S)}{\text{Var}(N)}$$ then the SNR doesn't change for two signals with different means (up to numerical precision). This is in contrast to computing the SNR with the mean, as I did in $$\frac{E[S^2]}{E[N^2]}$$

Comment: What is DC value?

Comment: Just means mean value. DC stands for “direct current” and comes from electronics.

Comment: I tried your formula in program, but it didn't give me same value. (See edited question)

Comment: Can't I use Mean Squared Error as SNR?

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira I added a code demo to my answer.

Comment: Why are we using variance? Can't I use MSE as SNR? Where predicted value is desired value (signal) and actual value is undesired value (noise). What do you think?